# A try-catch method in while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I have this code, and I want to put the try-catch inside a while loop. The logic would be, "while there is an input error, the program would keep on asking for a correct input". How will I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Random1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int g;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = r.nextInt(10) + 1;


    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        g = input.nextInt();
        if (g == a) {

            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("*  YOU WON!  *");
            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");

        } else if (g != a) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, better luck next time!");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Not a valid input. Error :" + e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: Where's your while loop and your attempt to solve this yourself first? Doing this will a) help you learn more, b) show us where your assumptions are incorrect and allow us to offer much better directed help, and c) greatly increase our respect for you.

Comment: Why writing answers to this question? Let the OP make the question clear first.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. Thanks as well. I'm just not that good at self studying. Again, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Here I have used **break** and **continue** keyword.

```
while(true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        g = input.nextInt();
        if (g == a) {

            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("*  YOU WON!  *");
            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");

        } else if (g != a) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, better luck next time!");
        }
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Not a valid input. Error :" + e.getMessage());
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `break` is in the wrong location, but this is a valid approach.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer helped me. One thing though. The logic worked when I checked for an `InputMismatchException` but doesn't work when I when I just catch an `Exception`. In the latter case, the catch block keeps executing inside the loop. WHY DOES THAT HAPPEN?

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean gotCorrect = false;
while(!gotCorrect){
  try{
    //your logic
    gotCorrect = true;
  }catch(Exception e){
     continue;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `break;` as the last line in the `try` block. That way, if any execption is thrown, control skips the `break` and moves into the `catch` block. But if not exception is thrown, the program will run down to the `break` statement which will exit the `while` loop.

If this is the only condition, then the loop should look like `while(true) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a boolean flag that you flip as appropriate.

Pseudo-code below

```
bool promptUser = true;
while(promptUser)
{
    try
    {
        //Prompt user
        //if valid set promptUser = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Do nothing, the loop will re-occur since promptUser is still true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block write `'continue;'`   :)