# How to get a try-catch equation to run more than once`

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I need to get this try-catch equation to run more than one time, if it detects an error (input of a letter or symbol)  How would I get that? I tried putting a second try catch with the same code, but it did not work.

```
    Try
        a = (Console.ReadLine())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Type Integer only. Try again.")
    End Try
```

I'm using VB.Net '08 edition

Comment: Maybe a For Loop? Or you could use a While Loop. Heck... [any old loop should do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx).

Comment: You've got several issues here. First, you really [shouldn't be relying on implicit conversion](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/articles/vb-net/converting-strings-to-numbers/). Second, exceptions should not be part of your normal workflow. If the user is likely to type non-integers, don't use an exception to catch non-integers... use proper logic (like [`If Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like JDB pointed out, you should not use exception in normal flow. And ReadLine returns a string, not a integer.

```
    Do
        Dim input As String

        input = Console.ReadLine()

        If Int32.TryParse(input, a) Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Type Integer only. Try again.")
    Loop
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm! :D

Answer (score 1):

You may try to put it in a loop with some condition like :

```
bool tryAgain = true;
while(tryAgain){
 try{
  //your code here
 }catch(Exception e){
  //your exception here
 }
}
```

Also do ensure that you do not run into infinite loop so do check your while or looping condition correct.

Comment: Make sure you remember to set the tryagain variable to false if no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781373/a-try-catch-method-in-while-loop)

```
correct = false;

while(!correct){
  Try   
    a = (Console.ReadLine())
  correct = true;
  Catch(Exception e){
  Console.WriteLine("Type Integer only. Try again.")
     continue;
}
```